# Sort Users based on specific Value(string) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to sort users based on the specific value. For example I have `Users table` and has relation with `Profiles Table`. In the `Profiles table` I have saved `Country (string)` of the user.

Now I want to sort specific country users first and then the other country Users.

Please guide me how can I do this in Laravel. 
Thanks

Comment: what did you try till now?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with that code.

```
$users = Users::with(['profiles' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('country', 'USA');
    $query->orWhere('country', 'Poland')
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not check this but You may try this solution. It will help you.

```
$users = Users::with(['profiles' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy("country='your country name'", 'DESC')
    $query->orderBy('country', 'ASC')
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$users = Users::with(['profiles' => function ($query) use($country) {
$query->orderBy(DB::raw('case when country="'.$country.'" then 1 else 2 end'))->orderBy('country', 'ASC');
}])->get();
```